# XML DOM Parser: null value of all element

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, dom

I try parse xml file, it is true length of element, but when I try get value of this tag element - it's null. Why?

My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <name>first</name>
    <name>second</name>
    <name>third</name>
</data>
```

DOM parser code(create three radioButton, but value of this is null):

```
NodeList name = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");

for (int x = 0; x < name.getLength(); x++) {
              Node nNode = name.item(x);
              radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
              group.addView(radioButton);
              radioButton.setId(x);
              radioButton.setText(nNode.getNodeValue());
              radioButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);            
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of nNode.getNodeValue() use nNode.getTextContent().